# How to destroy ExtJS application?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am writing unit tests for my ExtJS application.
I use an authentication method that creates the application upon successful authentication.

But I run into problems if I want to execute this method more than once, since the application would be created more than once.

How can I destroy the ExtJS application?

MyApp.destroy() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ext JS 4, Controllers and Applications do not support destroying. You can destroy and recreate the Viewport as @chinabuffet suggests, but you should assume that Application object is immortal and refactor your app logic around that.

Answer (score 1):

What about it isn't working exactly?

If there are Views leftover on the page, you might need to do something along the lines of `Ext.Viewport.removeAll(true, true);`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a flag setter to the initialization function so that when the application successfully authenticates, you set for example MyApp.alreadyInitiated = true;

In the init function, just add a check

```
    if (MyApp.alreadyInitiated) { 
        return;
    }
    MyApp.alreadyInitiated = true;
```

Or if you don't like multiple returns, just use !MyApp.alreadyInitiated and only run the code if it passes.